# WHERE clause in SQLite in a Java program not working

Tags: java, sqlite

I'm having a very strange problem. I am using SQLite in my java program. I use the jar provided at https://bitbucket.org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc. Executing statements works perfectly except if I use a 'WHERE' clause. For example, the following statement deletes everything:

```
PreparedStatement stmnt = con.prepareStatement("DELETE FROM pos_payment");
stmnt.executeUpdate();
```

but the following statement does not do anything even though I am 100% sure that a row with id = 0 exists:

```
stmnt = local.prepareStatement("DELETE FROM pos_payment WHERE pos_payment_id = ?");
stmnt.setInt(1, value);
stmnt.executeUpdate();
```

'value' is an integer, and the column 'pos_payment_id' is defined as such:

```
pos_payment_id int auto_increment PRIMARY KEY
```

I also tried the 'WHERE' clause in a 'SELECT' statement and it didn't work either. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: A row with id = 0? Are you sure that's right, id should start at 1.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I looked into the matter and found out that when I defined my column like this: 'pos_payment_id int PRIMARY KEY auto_increment' the column was not being treated as an autoincrement column and instead the value 0 was being inserted. When I changed it to 'pos_payment_id integer PRIMARY KEY' the autoincrement worked automatically.

Comment: That makes sense. Your old syntax would work in MySQL, but the new syntax is how it's done in SQLite.